# How to require local library mysql2 in ruby project

Tags: ruby

I have used bundler "bundle install --path vendor/bundle" to install my gem mysql2 in my project.

My Gemfile was like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
```

Now i want to require this gem in my ruby script but it is not working. Always shows "no such file mysql2".

My code is like this

```
require 'json'
    load_paths = Dir.pwd + "/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/"
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift(*load_paths)
    require 'mysql2'

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    # # TODO implement
    @db_host  = "host"
    @db_user  = "user"
    @db_pass  = "pass"
    @db_name = "db"

    client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => @db_host, :username => @db_user, :password => @db_pass, :database => @db_name)
    @cdr_result = client.query("SELECT count(*) from table_name")
    puts @cdr_result
    { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.generate('Hello from Lambda!') }

 end
```

error is comming like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from replaceFile.rb:4:in `<main>'
        1: from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2 (LoadError)
```

I am using ruby version = ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

Using options is not enough : you need to configure bundler so it can remember it. Here is what the [documentation](https://bundler.io/v1.17/man/bundle-config.1.html#REMEMBERING-OPTIONS) says :

```
Flags passed to bundle install or the Bundler runtime, such as --path foo or 
--without production, are not remembered between commands. If these options 
must be remembered, they must be set using bundle config (e.g., bundle config 
path foo).
```

Until you do that, bundler is going to ignore the local installation that you did and still try to fetch gems like it does usually i.e. not in the `vendor/bundle` path. Hence the failure